# Triangle area equals quadrilateral area

Tags: geometry

Here is a diagram and challenge description that should be clear and simple to understand.

[image]

Comment: How did you find the midpoint without a compass?

Comment: The midpoints are provided.

Comment: I know that, I'm asking how *you* got them, and why can't we have the same tools?

Comment: So the ruler can only be used to draw lines between two points and the intersection of any two lines can be viewed as a point?

Comment: It's easy if you use a compass - just use shear transformations.

Comment: @KSmarts This is the puzzle! I could do it starting with this layout. Can you?

Comment: @Joe The ruler is used to draw lines going through two points. Points, additional, are defined by two intersecting lines. You need to draw lines through using the six given points to create a triangle (1, 2, or 3 new points) with an area of it equal to the shaded area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a line segment starting at $A$, through $D$.
Make a line segment starting at $C$, through $B$.
Call the point where they intersect $G$.

[image]

The triangle $EFG$ has the same area as the quadrilateral.

Proof:
Extend $ED$ and draw a line segment starting at $B$ and running parallel to $CD$, call the point where they intersect $X$.

[image]

I know that triangle $EFX$ has the same area as the quadrilateral because triangle $DFB$ and triangle $DFX$ have the same area (same base and height). Unfortunately, I can't draw line $BX$, but I can use the same proof by splitting the quadrilateral into 2 quadrilaterals.

Point $E$ bisects segment $AB$. Therefore, if I draw a line parallel to $AD$ starting at $E$, it will bisect $DB$.
Similarly, point $F$ bisects segment $CD$. Therefore, if I draw a line parallel to $CB$ starting at $F$, it will bisect $BD$.
Call that point $H$ and draw a line starting at point $G$, through $H$ until it intersects $EF$. Call that point $I$.

[image]

$DG$ is parallel to $EH$ and therefore $EIG$ has the same area as $IEDH$.
$BG$ is parallel to $FH$ and therefore $IFG$ has the same area as $IFBH$.
Together this means that $EFG$ has the same area as $EFBD$.

The lines drawn in the proof can't be drawn using just a ruler, but that is unimportant.

Comment: How do triangles DFB and DFX have the same height?

Comment: Height of both is the distance between the parallel lines.

Comment: And how do you construct BX to be parallel with only an unmarked ruler?

Comment: You can't. You only need to get point G with the ruler. Everything after that is the proof. It doesn't need to be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

If I am allowed to measure distances with the ruler, then it would work to

> measure the distance from the crossing point if the two long lines to the point B and replicate that distance from E towards A, calling the new point G. Since FDG has the sum of the perpendicular heights of the two triangles that have FD as a base, it has the same area as the quadrilateral.

Of course if you mean ruler as in the classical ruler and compass construction, without the compass, I'm more stuck!

Comment: The idea is of a ruler without marking. No measurement is possible, even not adding markings:)

Comment: @Moti Hmmmm. back to the drawing board.